# Uploading Ionic Video Capture to Firebase Storage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a video capture to firebase storage but the upload file becomes corrupt or the blob isn't in the right format when I do so.

```
$scope.takeVideo = function () {
    var options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: false,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 100,
        targetHeight: 100,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: false,
        duration: 10
    };

    $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function (imageData) {
        $scope.video = imageData[0];
        var videoBlob = new Blob([$scope.video], { type: "video/mp4" });
        VideosFactory.SaveVideo(function (data) {
            $scope.video = data;
            $scope.SendPuzzleToFactory();
        }, $scope.video.name, videoBlob);
    }, function (err) {
        // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
}
```

VideosFactory.SaveVideo Method

```
SaveVideo: function (callback, referenceName, videoFile) {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var videosRef = storageRef.child('videos/' + $rootScope.User.uid + "/" + referenceName);
        var uploadTask = videosRef.put(videoFile);
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
            // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
            // See below for more detail
        }, function (error) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads, alert with error message
            reject(error)
        }, function () {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;

            // when done, pass back information on the saved image
            callback(downloadURL)
        });
    }
```

[image: Video upload screenshot]

When I try to download that from the console or download it through code, it won't work.

**Update**
Below is the file that I get from the video capture.

MediaFile

```
{
end: 0
fullPath: "file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160924_162045.mp4"
lastModified: null
lastModifiedDate: 1474748448000
localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20160924_162045.mp4"
name: "VID_20160924_162045.mp4"
size: 8083778
start: 0
type: "video/mp4"
}
```

I need to convert that to a blob basically.

**Update 2**
I have change the captureVideo method with the below code to convert the file to base64.

```
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function (videoData) {
        var video = videoData[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader(), file;
        fileReader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
            var base64 = readerEvt.target.result;
            var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: "video/mp4" });
            $scope.video = blob;
            VideosFactory.SaveVideo(function (data) {
                $scope.video = data;
                $scope.SendPuzzleToFactory();
            }, $scope.video.name, blob);
        };
        file = new window.File(video.name, video.localURL,
                               video.type, video.lastModifiedDate, video.size);
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }, function (err) {
        // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
```

Comment: any solutions yet??

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to resolve it yet. However I feel like I am on the right track. I have updated my question with what I have found so far.

Comment: Image upload is relatively easier however, i am going with my own server for video upload

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work with '@ionic-native/file'
With the help of this libary you can get the Data URL of selected video
So you need to do the following change

```
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function (imageData) {
    var fullPath = imageData[0].fullPath;
    var directoryPath = fullPath.substr(0, fullPath.lastIndexOf('/')); // URL to directory without filename
    var fileName = fullPath.substr(fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // filename with extension
    $file.readAsDataURL(directoryPath, fileName).then((dataURL) => {
        $scope.video = dataURL;
    }, (err) => {
        // Handle errors here
    });
}, function (err) {
    // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
});
```

In SaveVideo method do the following change

```
var uploadTask = videosRef.putString(videoFile, 'data_url', { contentType: 'video/mp4' });
```

I think this will help. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I assume (because I know nothing about Cordova or video capture), that the issue here is in this snippet:

```
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function (imageData) {
  $scope.video = imageData[0];
  var videoBlob = new Blob([$scope.video], { type: "video/mp4" });
  ...
});
```

Looks to me like `imageData[0]` would pull off the first byte or so of the video, while you likely want all of it. Changing this to be

```
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function (imageData) {
  var videoBlob = new Blob([imageData], { type: "video/mp4" });
  ...
});
```

Seems like it might work.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the case. The imageData is an array of objects. First one being the first video.